# How to find growth rate of function?

Tags: algorithm, asymptote

I have three functions, and I have to order them according to their relative growth rates (in increasing order). Following are the functions given:

> f(x)=[image]
>
> f(x)=[image]
>
> f(x)=[image]

I am not understanding that how do I find growth rate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: This has explained about "Big O". And I am interested to know that how can I find growth rate?

Answer (score 0):

To find the growth rate, you could use a spreadsheet and draw graphs for different values.

Once you've done that, take a graph and look at the shape and place them in order of how they grow. Here's a clue 20 * n^18 is much much bigger than log20(n^18).

Comment: Is this the only method for finding a growth rate? As creating graphs in exams is an expensive solution. So, kindly will you suggest me another solution for this?